# Who has built the house of Mason?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

Once upon a time, there was a mason (a man who can build house from stone) in a village. He builds the houses of those who do not build their house by themselves. The question is: Who builds the house of the mason?

Comment: Isn't it a paradox?

Comment: I think for paradox it should be only one mason in the village.

Comment: The carpenter did.

Comment: how @user121049 ?

Comment: We don't know the mason's house is made of stone, so perhaps it is made of wood.

Comment: Link: [Martin Gardner explains Russell's paradox in a simple, clear manner](https://www.mlook.mobi/files/month_1203/5ad8c76a68a6bf43161dedb124f53f5478c5a88a.pdf#page=23).

Answer (score 1):

You have just stated a less abstract version of [Russell's paradox](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox).

He suggested 'the predicate: to be a predicate which cannot be predicated of itself', and asked whether it could be predicated of itself. If it could, then it couldn't and vice-president. The paradox you mentioned above is hence a less abstract version of Russell's paradox.